# why does pickadate doesn't set input date?

Tags: datepicker

Hi I'm using pickadate and for some reason the date in my input field is not showing as the date when opening the picker.
Secondly the year picker is never shown.

```
$("input").click(function(){
        $("#inputdate").pickadate({
            monthSelector: true,
            yearSelector: true,
            format:'ddd, d mmm'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization of the plugin is occurring when the input is clicked; the same input that is to have the plugin applied. The plugin needs to be initialized on the input before the input is clicked. To do this, remove the click function:

```
$("#inputdate").pickadate({
    monthSelector: true,
    yearSelector: true,
    format:'ddd, d mmm'
});
```